# print linked list error. What's wrong?

Tags: c++

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

Node *AppendNode(Node *head, int data) {
    Node *ptr = head;

    struct Node node = {data, ptr->next};

    head->next = &node;

    return head;
}

void PrintNode(Node *head) {
    Node *ptr = head;
    while (ptr != 0) {
        printf("%d ", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}


int main() {

    Node node = {1 , 0};
    Node* head = &node;
    head = AppendNode(head, 2);
    PrintNode(head);



    return 0;
}
```

Output is (1,3830) instead of (1,2). Check debuggers I saw node value changes from 2 to 3830 in this step `ptr = ptr->next`; inside PrintNode. Sorry I am new to C++.

Comment: Your AppendNode function is wrong.  You are taking the address of a local variable.  The node variable should instead be a pointer to a Node created on the heap via new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
Node *AppendNode(Node *head, int data) {
    Node *ptr = head;

    struct Node node = {data, ptr->next};

    head->next = &node;

    return head;
}
```

You are inserting a pointer to a local stack variable into your linked list. As soon as your function returns, the memory referenced by `&node` is going to be clobbered pretty soon.

Also, whatever `head->next` was previously pointing to before the assignment is getting leaked (and lost).

Better:

```
Node* AppendNode(Node *head, int data)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
    return head;
}
```

But technically the above is "prepending" to the list, not "appending" as your function signature suggests.  Maybe that's what you want, but if not, that's an exercise I'll leave up to you. :)

As the other answer from Bo mentions, don't forget to call "delete" on your nodes when you are done with the list to avoid the memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

You have a local `Node` in `AppendNode`. As soon as you leave the function, that node is gone.

If you must create nodes dynamically, you do that with `new Node`. Just don't forget to `delete` the nodes later.